# Simple link to page works on xdk app preview but not work when I build the app

Tags: intel-xdk

A simple link in the simplest xdk html5 app, let's say, a link to Google for example (`<a href="http://google.com">click me</a>`) works on app preview. But, when I build the app, download the apk and install on my tablet, the same link don't work. Here is what I have done:

1. Created the apk using phonegap builder and it worked. Same code.
2. Include all plugins on xdk, used all types of script like loadExternal. Same result. All of the methods worked on app preview but not when actually build it.
3. Try to use "mailto:" links to open the e-mail, same thing.
4. A simple ping ajax request work on app preview and not on built apk.
5. It looks like that the internet connection is blocked to the built app.
6. Again, the same simple html5 app, not the hybrid app, it works perfectly opening a simple link to external page. The same html5 simple app don't open the damn link on built apk.

So, temporarily, I'll have to compile the app with phonegap builder, but, I really liked Intel xdk. How can I make the app work with xdk?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Intel XDK project settings to whitelist the websites you want the app to allow, set this to `*` to allow app to access any website

[image]

Comment: Yes! It worked. Thank you a lot! And I marked the check button (Allow external applications to launch...) too. Again, thank you!